# State Space Model of a transfer function

Tags: control-engineering, pid-control, systems-engineering, systems-design

[image]
where  we will attempt to stabilize it using the proportional
control law u(t) = Ke(t).

My Question is, how do I obtain the open-loop transfer function  from this dynamics system ? I assume that the above information of the system gives me the transfer function of the compensator only.  I was not given the plant transfer function G(s.  I am supposed to perform a Nyquist analysis but cant get the OL TF.

Thank you

Comment: What is $e(t)$?

Answer (score 1):

> I assume that the above information of the system gives me the transfer function of the compensator only.

This doesn't match with the problem statement.

> The dynamics of a **physical system** is given by...

The above description very likely means that the system to be controlled is given by the three equations above.

The system is described as a [state space model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-space_representation#Linear_systems). The (open loop) transfer function is given by the expression [$C(sI-A)^{-1}B$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-space_representation#Transfer_function) (not accounting for $e(t)$ since it is not specified; if specified, it should be possible to incorporate it into the $y=$ equation).